# Failed to connect to camera after releasing it

Tags: android, android-camera

This code is for a button to stops the strobe flashing in my flashlight app

```
 ...   else {
                cam.release();
                runner.requestStop = true;       
                on = false;
                strobedash.setImageResource(R.drawable.strobesoff);

                cam = Camera.open();    //opening it again
                p = cam.getParameters();

            }
```

This code turn the strobe off then releases the camera , then opens it again.It crashes when clicked and says "Failed to connect to camera service".The problem is that a second button uses the camera also for normal flash (not strobe) so it needs the camera to be opened.